# Adicionar formulário para subscrever a newsletter em c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, newsletter

Viva. Estou a desenvolver um website em c#, asp.net com recurso ao visual studio. Gostava de colocar um pequeno formulário onde o visualizador do site coloca o seu email para subscrever a uma newsletter. Já pesquisei formas de o fazer mas não encontrei nenhuma correta. Não sei como funciona, se é necessário recursos a outras ferramentas, etc..

Algo do género -> [image]
(feito no WIX.com)

Código utilizado para realziar esta operação:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();            
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
mail.To = "user@hotmail.com"; //
mail.From = "you@yourcompany.com";
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Tente melhorar sua pergunta. poste o que já tem feiro para que alguém posso te ajudar.

Comment: Eu tenho um site inteiro feito, só não está em produção ainda. Já editei a pergunta com um exemplo que eu fiz no site Wix.com

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isso que quer :

**Modelo**

```
public class Pessoa
{

    // No seu caso, acho que esse campo é opcional.
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Actions dentro do Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Pessoa pessoa)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Grava no banco ou o que quiser que seja feito.
    }

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@model SeuProjeto.Model.Pessoa

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SeuController", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o email">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
}
```

Comment: Parece-me bem. Mas como faço para receber essa informação, por exemplo, no meu mail? Ou neste caso, no mail da empresa?

Comment: Coloque no controller dentro do metodo que recebe o post, as ações para envio de email. Veja esse link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp

Comment: Não consegui.. simplesmente não faz nada! Será por a pergunta ser antiga?

Comment: Creio que não. Uso o mesmo mecanismo até hoje, funcionando normalmente. Vc alterou os parametros para envio de email de acordo com seu ambiente ?? Host, Port, etc...

Comment: Eu utilizei o código que coloquei na pergunta(editei) mas não funciona